# Get .value property from combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have used the following code...

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Value = "M232M2333";
item.Text = "Apples";
comboSpriteSelect.Items.Add(item);
```

This is an example but in reality I'm reading hundreds of these values from a text file and applying them to the combobox.

I don't seem to be able to get the `.Value` property back when I use `.SelectedValue`, but when I debug I see the value is assigned to the combobox.

```
lbl1.Text = comboSpriteSelect.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Can anyone provide a solution? Is it because I'm not binding data?

Comment: lbl1.Text =(ComboboxItem)comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem).Value.ToString(); did the trick, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have `ComboboxItem object in combo items`. Get the ComboboxItem from SelectedItem and take the value back of ComboboxItem class by casting the SelectedItem back to ComboboxItem .

```
lbl1.Text = ((ComboboxItem)comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem).Value;
```

If `Value is not string` then you may need to call ToString() on it

```
lbl1.Text = ((ComboboxItem)comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();
```

Comment: That returns an object, not a string?

Comment: Try  lbl1.Text = ((ComboboxItem)comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();

Comment: In ComboboxItem what is type of value?

Answer (score 3):

It is because you aren't databinding.  The [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) states that [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) is determined by the [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) property, which hasn't been set in your example.

Use

```
lbl1.Text = ((ComboboxItem)comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem).Value;
```

instead.

Comment: That returns an object, not a string?

Answer (score 1):

`lbl1.Text = comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem.ToString();` Instead of SelectedValue

Comment: That just returns the text value

Answer (score 0):

Override `ToString` in your `ComboboxItem` class

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return Value;
}
```

And then calling `comboSpriteSelect.SelectedItem.ToString();` will return item's value;